Error: package io.jsonwebtoken.impl.compression does not exist
I started getting the error below, when I upgraded jsonwebtoken dependency to the version 0.12.5
Any idea how to resolve this issue?
Error: package io.jsonwebtoken.impl.compression does not exist.
Here is my maven dependencies:
 <dependency>
    <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
    <artifactId>jjwt-api</artifactId>
    <version>0.12.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
    <artifactId>jjwt-impl</artifactId>
    <version>0.12.5</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
    <artifactId>jjwt-jackson</artifactId>
    <version>0.12.5</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>

Java import:
import io.jsonwebtoken.impl.compression.GzipCompressionCodec;


From 'io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-impl:0.12.0', GzipCompressionCodec has been removed.
Instead, a similar class GzipCompressionAlgorithm has been introduced.
You can find more details at the following  link.
* Removed all usages of CompressionCodecs.java in favor of a new Jwts.ZIP entry.
Renamed all Standard***AlgorithmsBridge to Standard***Algorithms

https://github.com/jwtk/jjwt/commit/529f04dd9097331220c3239bdadacee6b1dfd6de
/*
 * Copyright (C) 2015 jsonwebtoken.io
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */
package io.jsonwebtoken.impl.compression;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream;
import java.util.zip.GZIPOutputStream;

/**
 * Codec implementing the <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gzip">gzip compression algorithm</a>.
 *
 * @since 0.6.0
 */
public class GzipCompressionAlgorithm extends AbstractCompressionAlgorithm {

    private static final String ID = "GZIP";

    public GzipCompressionAlgorithm() {
        super(ID);
    }

    @Override
    protected OutputStream doCompress(OutputStream out) throws IOException {
        return new GZIPOutputStream(out);
    }

    @Override
    protected InputStream doDecompress(InputStream is) throws IOException {
        return new GZIPInputStream(is);
    }
}

If you want to use GzipCompressionCodec, you need to use a version of io.jsonwebtoken that is 0.11.5 or earlier.
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.jsonwebtoken/jjwt-impl -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
    <artifactId>jjwt-impl</artifactId>
    <version>0.11.5</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>


You mentioned you couldn't find GzipCompressionAlgorithm, so I added an image for better understanding.
have a nice day - kevin


I couldn't find GzipCompressionAlgorithm in io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-impl:0.12.0

To find it, you might want to change the scope to "compile."
<dependency>     <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>     <artifactId>jjwt-impl</artifactId>     <version>0.12.5</version>     <scope>compile</scope> </dependency>

I added an image showing that GzipCompressionAlgorithm is included in io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-impl:0.12.0! Hope this helps with understanding :)

It looks like GzipCompressionAlgorithm is different from GzipCompressionCodec.
I started getting this error: io.jsonwebtoken.security.WeakKeyException: The verification key's size is 336 bits which is not secure enough for the HS512 algorithm. The JWT JWA Specification (RFC 7518, Section 3.2) states that keys used with HS512 MUST have a size >= 512 bits (the key size must be greater than or equal to the hash output size). Consider using the Jwts.SIG.HS512.key() builder to create a key guaranteed to be secure enough for HS512.

Of course, the GzipCompressionAlgorithm is different from the GzipCompressionCodec. In your case, the exception occurred because the size of the key used for verification is too small.
The current key size is 336 bits, but the HS512 algorithm requires a minimum key size of 512 bits. Therefore, you need to increase the size of the key.

You can use the following key, which is suitable for the HS512 algorithm:
4lR1x5b2Ukc8j7B9s6JdP1y2ZtE3W9x7z2Q5u8X4a3J7o2L6c3W1p7H2q8N9m0V4
